# ¿como pasar elementos clasificados a otro arreglo en c++ o en c?

Tags: c++, array, c

tengo el siguiente código y tengo un gran problema es que quisiera pasar a el arreglo n todos los elementos menos  el numero tres, así que si es el numero tres ,me pase a la siguiente iteración ,y si la siguiente iteración no es el numero tres me la pase al otro arreglo ,pero cuando compilo el algoritmo no funciona como deberia funcionar ,¿alguien sabe como corregirlo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m[5]={1,2,2,3,4};
    int n[5]={0};
    for(int i=0;i!=5;i++){
        
     if(m[i]==3){
         
      continue;
            
     }else{
        
         m[i]=n[i];
         
         
         }
     
   }
   for(int i=0;i!=5;i++){
       
       cout<<n[i]<<endl;
       
   }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No debería ser `if(i==3)` que es el tercer elemento?

Comment: Yo he entendido que si el elemento del array es el número 3, no el índice... Pero la verdad es que puede ser cualquier cosa porque no lo he entendido del todo lo que quiere hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int m[5] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
int n[5] = {0};
int indice = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(m[i] != 3)
   {
      n[indice] = m[i];
      indice++;
   }
}
```

Lo que hacemos hasta aquí es ir recorriendo el **arreglo m** y solamente guardar en el **arreglo n** los elementos del **arreglo m** que no sean **3**.

Utilizamos la **variable indice** que nos servirá precisamente como un índice para saber en que posición del **arreglo n** tenemos que guardar el elemento del **arreglo m**, es decir si encontramos un elemento **distinto de 3** en el **arreglo m** entonces guardamos este elemento en el **arreglo n** e incrementamos la **variable indice**, de ser **3**, entonces no guardamos el elemento del **arreglo m** en la posición que indica la **variable indice** en el **arreglo n** y no incrementamos la **variable indice**.

Hacerlo de esta forma nos evita tener huecos intermedios(elementos con el valor de **0**) en el **arreglo n**, ya que solamente incrementamos la **variable indice** cuando encontramos un elemento distinto a **3**.

Y para imprimir los elementos guardados en el **arreglo n** hacemos lo siguiente:

```
for(int i = 0; i < indice; i++)
{
   //Imprimimos el elemento
}
```

Fíjate que usamos como limite la **variable indice**, ya que indica la cantidad de elementos válidos que introducimos en el **arreglo n**.

Comment: gracias esto era lo que estaba buscando ,había buscado unos algoritmos que eran totalmente diferente a  este ,pero incrementaban la posición dentro del if y no entendía porque ,gracias me as solucionado un gran problema

Comment: Por favor acepta la respuesta si te sirvio, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si no lo he entendido mal... Quieres que cuando en tu array `m` tengas el número `3`, éste no se guarde en el array `n`.
Tienes varias cosas mal planteadas:

1. El limitador del bucle `for`.
2. La asignación del array. Estás asignando en tu array ya existente el valor de la misma posición del array `n`, cuando creo que quieres hacer lo contrario.

El código que buscas es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m[5]={1,2,3,3,4};
    int n[5]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // Crea array n
    {
        if(m[i]==3)
            continue;
        else
            n[i]=m[i];
   }

   for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // Imprime array n
   {
      cout<<n[i]<<endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución es:

```
1
2
2
0
4
```

ya que se tiene:

```
m = { 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 }
      |   |   |   |   |
      OK  OK  OK  0   OK
      |   |   |   |   |
       \   \   \   \   \
  n = { 1 , 2 , 2 , 0 , 4 }
```

En el caso de que quieras que cuando se encuentre el número `3`, bastaría con implementar la lógica de desplazar a la izquierda las posiciones que vengan detrás en relación a tu índice de control del `for`.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué significa el comentario `// Crea array n`? ¡El *array n* ya está creado!

Comment: Me refería a que construye el array `n` con la información que se quiere. Me habré explicado mal, pero es un simple bucle, en el que se entiende bastante bien la funcionalidad que se lleva a cabo.

Comment: Es que no construye el array `n`, dicho array se ha creado en el momento de definirlo en las primeras líneas de `main`. En todo caso ese bucle rellenará un bucle, pero no lo creará.

Answer (score 0):

Estás copiando en la formación `m`:

```
m[i]=n[i];
```

Pero parece que esperabas haber copiado en la formación `n`, que es la que estás mostrando:

```
for(int i=0;i!=5;i++){
       
    cout<<n[i]<<endl;
//        ^ <--- 'n', pero has copiado en 'm'       
}
```

Con la corrección pertinente (`n[i]=m[i];`) [el resultado](https://tio.run/##fY7LbsMgEEX38xVE2TjKQ26TrID8SJQFwpN0JHtsGVhZ/nbHENdOW6mDBFfnoAu2afa2NPwYhjWxLUOBQlHtfIumusDCRkL8OHxdILgxCDYVusZYFM4XEoDYi8oQZxvoAMQ4iVzPN9197D7HddydejkbTiafyL1us0hJ55JW@ixpu910ScV5Bbpn1ZVuWh/f1OSErdkTB5SLmWWPpcPfbXE41sVO@afvR@phBin@/93v09bBKxXfUAq5KOX7hVdl2lr0oWWRS@iH4Qk)  es el que supongo que esperas:

```
1
2
2
0
4
```

Esto te pasa por la mala práctica de usar nombres de variables que no son autoexplicativos, evita los nombres como `m`, `n` o `i`, que no dan ninguna información sobre la misión de esas variables, este código es mucho más claro, más fácil de leer y menos propenso a errores:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int origen[5]={1,2,2,3,4};
    int destino[5]={0};

    for (int indice = 0; i != 5; ++indice) {
        if (origen[indice] == 3) {
            continue;
        }

        destino[indice] = origen[indice];
    }

    for (const int &valor : destino) {
        cout << valor << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si lo que en realidad pretendes es copiar todo menos el `3` (es decir, filtrar los datos) puedes jugar con los punteros:

```
int origen[5]={1,2,2,3,4};
int destino[5]={0};

for (auto o = std::begin(origen), d = std::begin(destino), fin = std::end(origen);
    o != fin; ++o) {
    if (*o != 3) {
        *d = *o;
        ++d;
    }
}
```

Pero es algo que sólo aconsejaría usar en caso de no haber una alternativa más clara, que la hay:

```
int origen[5]={1,2,2,3,4};
int destino[5]={0};

std::copy_if(std::begin(origen), std::end(origen), std::begin(destino),
    [](int valor) { return valor != 3; });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LasMwEDxbX7GlUCxwIG3ai@3kR0IIqqyoAntlJLlQjL7dWVkOgaKLZnYeu3Icd1rKZXk1KPupU9Aa64NTYjixJyd6bZ0JP0QygwEGYbDkbGbF5A1qQDEoPwqpwIeuYaxIInJoheevy3F@rz7oHarP2ORZp3wwaNfhPiYHGeta2vHvam7lCr6VppacwitYOYXdPyartjxesaI4X8pU8St66zjM4FSYHGYML0c4NBB5qrwRLqVFHyAZ3rKifixHXkqTdgrQtpudPrRCT1dECtiS9w2Ly3IH)</kbd>.

Comment: creo que formule mal mi pregunta la intencion de mi programa es que pase el contenido del primer arreglo al segundo ,entonces si la primera posición del arreglo es igual a 3 use el continúe; y pase a la siguiente iteración del arreglo si la siguiente posición es diferente de 3 entonces me rellene la primera posición del segundo arreglo arreglo con esa iteración y así sucesivamente

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo o sea ¿Copiar todo menos el tres?

Comment: @ PaperBirdMaster si o el 4 o el 5 u otro numero